String brokes after splitted in C
I'm creating a serial port reader program using the GTK API with C. I'm encountering an issue where the original string received from the serial port loses its first character after splitting it into substrings.
while (1) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int len = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
    if (len > 0) {
        buffer[len] = '\0';
        printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);


        char splittedBuffer[5][1024];

        int dataIndex = 0;
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        
        printf("len is %d\n", len);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(buffer[i] == ';'){
                
                splittedBuffer[dataIndex][bufferIndex] = '\0';
                dataIndex ++;
                bufferIndex = 0;
                
            }else{
                splittedBuffer[dataIndex][bufferIndex] = buffer[i];
                bufferIndex++;

            }

            
        }

        printf("data0 : %s\n",splittedBuffer[0]);
        printf("data1 : %s\n",splittedBuffer[1]);
        printf("data2 : %s\n",splittedBuffer[2]);
        printf("data3 : %s\n",splittedBuffer[3]);
        printf("data4 : %s\n",splittedBuffer[4]);

        printf("after op: %s\n", buffer);
        
        
        

        
    } else if (len < 0) {
        perror("Error reading from serial port");
    }
}

(If you'd like to see the complete code, please feel free to ask it in the comments.)
I'd appreciate any insights into why the first character is disappearing after splitting.
and the output is;
Received: 23;10;20;30;40;

len is 16
data0 : 23
data1 : 10
data2 : 20
data3 : 30
data4 : 40
after op: 
3;10;20;30;40;

Received: 24;10;20;30;40;

len is 16
data0 : 24
data1 : 10
data2 : 20
data3 : 30
data4 : 40
after op: 
4;10;20;30;40;


We don't want to see the full code but some code that is complete enough to reproduce your issue. It should be possible to copy your code and compile it locally. See MCVE for details. For example, all the gtk* functions are not relevant as you print the strings to stdout.

@Gerhardh so you want me to delete irrelevant part

That would be nice. Using that GTK stuff makes it much more effort to reproduce your error. And of course you should add whatever is missing to make it compile. Maybe hard code your input etc...

Where do you get your input from? Your output shows 15 characters but len is 16.

Is there some space at the end of your input that is not visible?

@Gerhardh it is comming from serial port it is probably \n char

No, it can't be \n. You print "Received: %s\n", buffer. If there was a newline in the buffer, you would see an extra empty line which you don't. Anyway, there must be an extra character causing you to run beyond the limits as expained in Ted's answer.

Unless his posted output isn't precisely accurate

@TedB yes. I just realized I deleted one line. I will fix it now. I am new with the stack exchange and text editor is weird when copy pasting.

I would say that validates the assumption in my answer below.

OK, I assume now it is clear that providing an exact and complete copy of any input and output is important. ;)

23;10;20;30;40; is 15 characters in length.
When you've filled splittedBuffer[4] with 40, you go ahead with the 16:th character to fill ...
splittedBuffer[dataIndex][bufferIndex] = buffer[i];

... when dataIndex is 5, which is out of bounds, so the program has undefined behavior.
A quick fix would be to not continue when dataIndex goes out of bounds:
for (int i = 0; i < len && dataIndex < 5; i++) {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


New Edit:
In light of the comments and thinking about what's going on, I believe the last meaningful variable declaration before while (1) is char buffer[1024].
The stack grows downward, so this effectively becomes splittedBuffer[5], and the invisible character in buffer is '\n', which gets written to splittedBuffer[5][0], aka buffer[0].
int len almost certainly doesn't get allocated on the stack, instead being optimized to a register, leaving the buffers stacked on top of one another.
Previous:
Your output doesn't add up, but without a minimal reproducible example it's hard to see what else is going on.
Just going by the output len is 16 we can tell that either your example isn't the code you're running, or there's an invisible character in your input, as only 15 characters are being displayed.
If the output is accurate, buffer[0] is '\n' when after op: is printed - this is one reason to always wrap your debugging output in characters that do not appear in the data, as in
    printf("Received: '%s'\n", buffer);
    . . .
    printf("after op: '%s'\n", buffer);

Start there, and if the problem isn't clear post a better example.
Edit: As the other Ted points out, you've got an out-of-bounds issue as well that you definitely need to address, but the fact that your count doesn't match what's printed before you touch anything suggests a problem earlier than your splitting loop.

There's nothing suggesting an earlier problem that I can see. The remaining problem with OP's current approach is that he/she is using read and is expecting to get a full line/record in one read operation. That luckily succeeds (for now) so buffer most likely contains "23;10;20;30;40;\n". From there, the only problem was the continued parsing after the 5:th number which results in assigning the last character in buffer to splittedBuffer[5][0].

A trailing newline in buffer wouldn't explain the newline between after op: and the value. AH, but I know what would - needs an answer edit

It doesn't matter what's actually after the last ; in  buffer. The only thing that matters is that that character is written out of bounds and that makes the program have undefined behavior. With that, it could print anything or just crash or do something completely bonkers.

And out-of-bounds, in this case, could very well be the beginning of buffer, if (as I suspect) it's the last meaningful variable declaration before the while loop.

It could absolutely be that, but there is no rule saying that that is what happens. Different imlementations will likely have very different results when UB is involved.

Absolutely solidly into undefined behavior and there needs to be a check on dataIndex, but most compilers will lay out neatly power-of-two-sized elements quite predictably.

Yeah, and one could use the debugger to investigate how the implementation at hand does it. That would probably be a good idea anyway when the result is surprising :-)
